# Local and remote branch has been diverged?

Tags: git

Here is my situation

1. I checkout from main and make my feature branch “my branch “
2. I pushed my changes into remote “my branch”
3. Main got advanced with few merges from other people
4. Now I have worked more on my local branch , and want to do following
5. “ take all the changes of remote main , and put my local branch changes in top of them “
6. I have tried doing git rebase and pull but doing that just overwrite my local files and They are left with errors due to weird mismatch ( from my local and remote ) . Luckily I have staged and committed so no changes are lost

Comment: Side note: Pick *one* of GitHub or GitLab. As a rule of thumb, using both tags is probably wrong. (In this case both tags are probably irrelevant, so I've snipped them.)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you cannot do a pull. You did have the right idea though:

git rebase main

Then when locally everything is in order, force push (`git push --force`) to overwrite the remote "my branch", telling it that your state (which includes the commits added from main) is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say we have master, branch_A (made from master) and branch_B (also made from master). I am working on branch_A and my friend is working on branch_B. My friends work in branch_B was merged to master. Now I am done and I want to merge my branch to master as well. The process I would follow is below:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git pull` (update local master from with remote changes)
3. `git checkout branch_A`
4. `git rebase master` (this will pull in the changes from master and stack your branch commits on top)
5. `git push origin branch_A -f` (need force since you rebased which changes branch HEAD)

Hope that helps.